# React setState and streaming response

Tags: reactjs, stream, streaming

How do I deal with a streamed response ?

using the function approach of `setState` with functions doesn't seem to work:
the hooks are not executed in the correct order and the response is unordered

```
    const response = await fetch('/dostuff', {
      method:'POST',
      body
    })

    const reader = response.body!.getReader();
    const chunks = [];
    
    let done, value;
    while (!done) {
      ({ value, done } = await reader.read());
      if (done) {
        return chunks;
      }
      const strval = new TextDecoder().decode(value)
      chunks.push(strval);
      await setResponseText((prev)=> {
        return prev + strval
      })

      // console.log("EEE ",strval);          
    }
```

Comment: With such an incomplete code example it's difficult to say what or why the code isn't working as expected. Can you [edit] to provide a more complete [mcve] and example received chunked data, e.g. sample `reader.read()` values, so we've better context what the code can or should do?

Comment: that is literally 98% of the logic, the rest of the component is basically a div that show the responseText state.

Answer (score 1):

The useEffect hook is used to initiate the fetching process, and the responseText state is updated once at the end of the loop. This should help avoid potential issues with asynchronous state updates. You can add any dependencies that should trigger the effect to run again when they change.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const response = await fetch('/dostuff', {
        method: 'POST',
        body,
      });

      const reader = response.body.getReader();
      let chunks = '';

      while (true) {
        const { value, done } = await reader.read();

        if (done) {
          break;
        }

        const strVal = new TextDecoder().decode(value);
        chunks += strVal;
      }

      setResponseText(chunks);
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

Comment: thank you, but i need to show the text when a chunk arrive, having the setResponseText only at the end would produce no output to the user until the stream is finished; consider this an openAI response where it's nice to have output while the backend is producing it

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the StrictMode issue.  I would have spent way too many hours looking for that issue.

Answer (score 1):

In the end the issue was in two different points:

- decoder in the while loop
- react strict mode enabled and useEffect interaction.

**Decoder**

the decoder needed to be outside of the loop because the stream response could end in the middle of a multibyte character. creating a new decoder at each iteration does not allow to manage this case.

**Strict mode**

I honestly did not think that the useEffect hook was somehow involved in this error so I limited the code in the original question, my bad.

What happens is that in development mode, react strict mode causes the render and  mounting / unmounting of components twice.

This creates a racing condition because the first render's streamed response was still active and receiving data when the second render's streamed response started.

The state that contains the response text is therefore updated sometimes with a first stream data chunk, sometime with a second stream chunk.

The solution was therefore to add an AbortController in the useEffect call.

```
useEffect( ()=> {
  const controller = new AbortController();
  const run = async (controller:AbortController) => {   

    let response
    try {

      response = await fetch('/doStuff', {
        method:'POST',
        body
      })
      
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.name === "AbortError") {
        return;
      }
      ...
    }

    const reader = response.body!.getReader();
    const chunks = [];
    
    let done, value;
    const dec = new TextDecoder()

    while (!done) {
      ({ value, done } = await reader.read());
      if (done) {
        return chunks;
      }
      const strval = dec.decode(value, { stream: true })
      chunks.push(strval);
      text.current += strval
      setResponseText(text.current)      
    }


  }
  run(controller)

  return () => controller.abort();
  
},[])
```